# Constructing a ring consisting of formal infinite series from a given ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, graded-rings

Let $A$ be an $\mathbb{N}$-graded $\Bbbk$-algebra, where $\Bbbk$ is a field, and where $\dim_\Bbbk A_n < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. I can't see anything preventing me from constructing a ring $\widehat{A}$ whose elements are formal infinite sums $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n$, where $a_n \in A_n$, and with the obvious notions of addition and multiplication. An obvious special case is $\widehat{A} = \Bbbk[[x]]$ when $A = \Bbbk[x]$. However, I have a few questions related to this:

- Is the assumption $\dim_\Bbbk A_n < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ strictly necessary? If $\dim_\Bbbk A_n = \infty$ for some $n$, then the above construction doesn't seem to allow me to consider a formal infinite sum of basis elements of $A_n$. Is there a way around this?
- Are there any general advantages of looking at $\widehat{A}$ rather than $A$? For example, I believe that when $A = \Bbbk[x,y,z]/(xy-z^3)$, we get $\widehat{A} = \Bbbk[[x,y,z]]/(xy-z^3)$, where the finitely generated module category of the former is not Krull-Schmidt but that of the latter is.
- Can this process be extended to an arbitrary ring $R$? At the very least, a closed form for the product of two infinite series doesn't always seem to be possible.

Comment: 1. I can't see where $\dim_kA_n<\infty$ enters into the play. 2. In your last example what's the grading on $A$?

Comment: @user26857: I suppose $\deg x = 1, \deg y = 2, \deg z = 1$ means that my hypotheses hold, but perhaps I want $\deg x = 1, \deg y = -1, \deg z = 0$. I believe I might also want finitely generated module categories.

Comment: I've thought you are talking about a graded ring, not about the modules over this. And maybe the change of grading could change the ring $\hat A$, don't you think?

Comment: Yes, I'm foremost interested in the ring, but in the case of the second bullet point I believe that I need finitely generated modules. And yes, that could be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is always possible. No assumption on the dimensions are necessary, but you crucially need a $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$-grading and not a $\mathbb{Z}$-grading for multiplication to be well-defined. As an abelian group this ring is just $\prod_{n \in \mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}} A_n$ and multiplication can be given by a componentwise formula (essentially the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)).

Versions of this ring come up in topology and geometry, where certain infinite sums of characteristic classes are used such as the [Todd class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_class) or [Chern character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chern_class#The_Chern_character).

I don't know what you mean by extending the process to an arbitrary ring.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my suspicions :)